# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime when storing Peekable iterators in a vector

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime

The following code works perfectly:

```
use std::iter::Peekable;
use std::slice::Iter;

fn has_next(iter: &mut Peekable<Iter<usize>>) -> bool {
    match iter.peek() {
        Some(_) => true,
        None => false,
    }
}

fn print_iters(iters: &mut Vec<Peekable<Iter<usize>>>) {
    for iter in iters.iter_mut() {
        if has_next(iter) {
            match iter.next() {
                Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
                None => {}
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![2, 4, 6, 8];
    let v2 = vec![1, 3, 5, 7];
    let mut iters = Vec::new();
    iters.push((v1.iter().peekable()));
    iters.push((v2.iter().peekable()));
    print_iters(&mut iters);
}
```

In some code I wrote, I need to store the `Peekable`s in a vector and iterate using them at a later time. I tried modifying the code to this:

```
use std::iter::Peekable;
use std::slice::Iter;

fn has_next(iter: &mut Peekable<Iter<usize>>) -> bool {
    match iter.peek() {
        Some(_) => true,
        None => false,
    }
}

fn print_iters(iters: &mut Vec<Peekable<Iter<usize>>>) {
    for iter in iters.iter_mut() {
        if has_next(iter) {
            match iter.next() {
                Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
                None => {}
            }
        }
    }
}

fn init_iters(v: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, iters: &mut Vec<Peekable<Iter<usize>>>) {
    for i in v.iter() {
        iters.push(i.iter().peekable());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![2, 4, 6, 8];
    let v2 = vec![1, 3, 5, 7];
    let v = vec![v1, v2];
    let mut iters = Vec::new();
    init_iters(v, &mut iters);
    print_iters(&mut iters);
}
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:23:20
   |
23 |         for i in v.iter() {
   |                    ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 22:79...
  --> src/main.rs:22:80
   |
22 |       fn init_iters(v: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, iters: &mut Vec<Peekable<Iter<usize>>>) {
   |  ________________________________________________________________________________^
23 | |         for i in v.iter() {
24 | |             iters.push(i.iter().peekable());
25 | |         }
26 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:23:18
   |
23 |         for i in v.iter() {
   |                  ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the body at 22:79...
  --> src/main.rs:22:80
   |
22 |       fn init_iters(v: &Vec<Vec<usize>>, iters: &mut Vec<Peekable<Iter<usize>>>) {
   |  ________________________________________________________________________________^
23 | |         for i in v.iter() {
24 | |             iters.push(i.iter().peekable());
25 | |         }
26 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::iter::Peekable<std::slice::Iter<'_, _>>, found std::iter::Peekable<std::slice::Iter<'_, _>>)
  --> src/main.rs:24:24
   |
24 |             iters.push(i.iter().peekable());
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:33:20
   |
33 |         init_iters(v, &mut iters);
   |                    ^ expected reference, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<usize>>`
              found type `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<{integer}>>`
   = help: try with `&v`
```

Why do I get this error? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the rules of [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision) your function `init_iters` expands to

```
fn init_iters<'a, 'b, 'c>(v : &'a Vec<Vec<usize>>,
                          iters : &'b mut Vec<Peekable<Iter<'c, usize>>>) {
    for i in v.iter() {
        iters.push(i.iter().peekable());
    }
}
```

The vector's lifetime `'a` and `Iter`'s lifetime `'c` are declared as independent. The compiler doesn't try to infer lifetime bounds which are not explicitly specified. The error tells you that compiler cannot prove that `'c` will not outlive `'a` because they are declared as independent.

To fix it, you need to tell the compiler that `Iter` doesn't outlive the vector it refers to. Using the lifetime bound `'a: 'c` does it.

```
fn init_iters<'a: 'c, 'b, 'c>( ...
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fd80a2650c72f99b339b0905c93ecfdd&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I will learn about lifetime elision. It seems a little bit complicated at a first glance though. I made a small change to my code where I initialized the iters in main iteself without calling the function init_iters and it worked, so I guess in Rust we have to write code in such a way that we do not need to specify lifetime bounds.

Comment: A nice comment from here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetimes.html. "However it does mean that several programs that are totally correct with respect to Rust's true semantics are rejected because lifetimes are too dumb."

Comment: @vamsikal, it is not a case of "dumb lifetimes", it is a consequence of language design decision: "type inference doesn't cross function boundaries". When your code resides in `main`, compiler infers appropriate lifetimes and types of variables. When you move code into separate function, you will need to write the types of parameters and sometimes lifetimes' bounds.